# Writing client applications for protocols like SSL, openVPN , L2TP and etc

Tags: vb.net, ssl, tcp, udp, l2tp

I recently have made a vpn client application in vb.net that supports three protocols UDP, TCP and L2TP. Actually I did not write all the code by myself but I combined the pre written source code into one application. Now my client wants me to add support for SSL protocol into the application and I have no idea about coding this protocol. I just wanted to know about a resource i.e book or video training preferably in vb.net that will guide me in detail about developing vpn client applications for all protocols.

Comment: " Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "

Comment: Exactly so ... I'm confused in particular by the reference to OpenVPN in the title.  *(Does it, in fact, belong there?)*  You refer to it as "a VPN client application" but I don't understand what you mean.  The whole purpose of VPN (and, to a lesser extent, other "tunneling" technologies) is to relieve the client applications from having to know that the secure tunnel even *exists.*  Please revise your question with (considerable) detail.